# How can I convert a mpeg to a avi file using a linux live cd?

Tags: linux, livecd

Is any linux live cd distro for converting movies from mpeg to avi formats ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use KDENLive or VLC..and Handbrake is also nice option.
http://handbrake.fr/